# Error in nops_eval(register = "C:/Users....: length(attr(scans, "check")) == 0L is not TRUE

Tags: r, r-exams

When trying to mark an exam:

```
ev1 <- nops_eval(
  register =        "C:/Users/(...) /R_Exam2/nops_scan/lista.csv",
  solutions =       "C:/Users/(...) /R_Exam2/nops_pdf/BSc_Soc_MiniTeste3_20221116.rds",
  scans = Sys.glob( "C:/Users/(...) /R_Exam2/nops_scan/nops_scan_*.zip"),
  eval = exams_eval(partial = FALSE, negative = FALSE),
  interactive = FALSE,
  mark = FALSE,
  dir =             "C:/Users/(...) /R_Exam2/evaluation_sheets",
  file = "ADGRH_2022-23_Teste_results",
  results = "ADGRH_2022-23_Teste"
)
```

I receive the following error message

```
Error in nops_eval(register = "C:/Users/(...)/R_Exam2/nops_scan/lista.csv",  : 
  length(attr(scans, "check")) == 0L is not TRUE
```

The register file seems fine:

Following a post on  a similar issue, I have tried to redefine the column names and resave the csv file using `write.csv2`.

```
x <- read.csv2("C:/Users (...) /R_Exam2/nops_scan/lista.csv", colClasses = "character")

names(x)

names(x) <- c("registration", "name", "id")

write.csv2(x, "C:/Users (...) /R_Exam2/nops_scan/lista.csv")
```

but that did not work too.

Comment: This code you posted above has syntax errors (which is why the coloring is off). You seem to have double-double quotes at the start of some strings. Make sure you don't have that extra quote symbol at the start of your strings.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. The error in the syntax happened when I pasted the code - hiding some parts for privacy sake . There are no errors in the original code.

Comment: What version of the package are you using? It seems like at least the error message may be better in the latest version 2.4 https://github.com/cran/exams/blob/master/R/nops_eval.R#L95

Comment: I am indeed using an earlier version... I will update it and come back with feedback. Thank you again for your help!

Comment: @MrFlick Thanks for the support. I'm impressed that you chased down the change in the error message! Amilcar Moreira Indeed the error typically indicates some mismatch of student IDs from the scanned sheets with the IDs provided in the registration .csv file. Sometimes it's also a mismatch of the scanned exam IDs with the metainformation from the .rds file. In addition to the improved error message, the latest R/exams version on CRAN (2.4-0) also has much improved scanning facilities, so maybe the problem can be avoided altogether. Please follow up here so that we can resolve the question.

Comment: @AmilcarMoreira Any follow-up regarding this? Otherwise I would vote for closing the question because in the current form it's usefulness for other users will be rather limited.

Comment: @AmilcarMoreira I was just going through the open R/exams issues here on SO and noticed that this post is still pending as well. Do you have an update or can it be closed?

Comment: I've voted to close this question now for lack of clarity.  In the current form it is not possible to replicate the problem or answer the question and there was no follow-up by the original author in half a year.